# Allure report not resolving the SLF4J2 placeholder values

Tags: logging, log4j2, reporting, slf4j, allure

We are facing an issue with the log printing format in the Allure report after migrating to SLF4J with Log4j2 implementation. I would appreciate any assistance or suggestions to resolve this problem.

In SLF4J2 we just use the placeholders - {} and the dymanic values are resolved defaultly.

Sample method to print log statements in the Allure report:

```
@step("INFO: {0}")
public void logInfo(final String format, final Object... argArray) {
log.info(format, argArray);
}
```

For example, if we call logInfo("Value is {}", "sample"), we expect the log message in the Allure report to be displayed as "Value is sample" **resolving the placeholders**.
However, the actual log message shown in the Allure report is "Value is {}".

Our goal is to resolve this issue and achieve the expected result of the log printing in the Allure report in the desired format ("Value is sample").

Input - logInfo("Value is {}", "sample")
Expected Result - Value is sample
Actual Result - Value is {}

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or possible solutions to address this problem. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What is the fully-qualified class name of `log`?

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz
It is com.taf.logger and the class name is Logger and the log object is initialized as org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.class);

Comment: LogSLF4J behavior is that it replaces the placeholders - {} dynamically with the arguments. Allure report is not resolving this statement. Can we achieve this using Allure Report